# How to run Contact Sheet II on multiple files via JavaScript in photoshop?

Tags: javascript, java, photoshop

I tried to make a script to do this via photoshop. But unfortunately, no files will open in photoshop. Any help, please?
PS:

1. The name of files are: "D:/MyBook.jpg","D:/TheSun.jpg","D:/Car.jpg"
2. They should load in alphabetic order. I mean the script should load it in alphabetic order.

```
function createContactSheet(fileNames){
var id = stringIDToTypeID( "0B71D221-F8CE-11d2-B21B-0008C75B322C" );
    var desc1 = new ActionDescriptor();
    var idCSIISettings = stringIDToTypeID( "CSIISettings" );
    desc1.putString( idCSIISettings, '<ContactSheetIISettings>'+
  '<source imageSource="Files" selectFile="'+ fileNames +'"/>'+
  '<document units="pixels" width="910" height="25000" resolution="72" resUnits="pixels/inch" mode="RGB Color" bitDepth="8-bit" colorProfile="sRGB IEC61966-2.1" flattenLayers="true"/>'+
  '<thumbnail place="across first" cols="1" rows="100" bestFit="false" useAutospacing="true" horz="1 px" vert="1 px"/>'+
  '<caption enabled="false">'+
  '<font name="Arial" size="12"/>'+
  '</caption>'+
'</ContactSheetIISettings>' );
    var idMsge = charIDToTypeID( "Msge" );
    desc1.putString( idMsge, "Settings for Contact Sheet II" );
executeAction( id, desc1, DialogModes.NO );
}

var fileNames = new File ("D:/HardSub2SRT/Pic of Subs/J2testJva/0001.jpg","D:/MyBook.jpg","D:/TheSun.jpg","D:/Car.jpg");
$.setenv("NoUI",false);
createContactSheet(fileNames);
$.setenv("NoUI","");
```

Comment: [Java is not JavaScript!](http://javascriptisnotjava.com/)

Comment: What's wrong with using contact sheet normally?? - you can use on a folder or a number of files and even ave the save file list as XML.

Comment: What do you mean by normally? I need to make the sheet via script. Could you please kindly help me with scripting? Thanks.

Comment: Have you tried running contact sheet in Photoshop?

Comment: Yes. But I need to use via script. I don't understand the reason of this question you asked!